# Are there any contributed/commercial themes available for Open Atrium?

Tags: theming, distributions

Googling "Open Atrium Theme" doesn't yield very many results. I have a sinking feeling that most people who install Open Atrium stick with Ginko for the theme.

Are there any contributed themes out there for Open Atrium or Commercial Themes?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a bunch of them (scraped from [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aH_37ZnVqtJkJ%3ahttps://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/3456+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk), it seems the [original page](https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/3456) is no longer available):

- [Miro](http://morten.dk/blog/open-atrium-theme-miro)
- [Trapeze](https://github.com/technicolorenvy/trapeze)
- [Sandy](https://github.com/ademarco/sandy)
- [Scene](https://github.com/berkes/Atrium/tree/a9f59dd8bd9f625df1191f843eec631a9ee9031f/sites/all/themes/scene)
- [Mobile Gingko](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_ginkgo)
- [Atrium Simple](http://drupal.org/project/atrium_simple)
- [UNL](https://github.com/natebenes/unlatriumtheme)
- [Crystal](https://github.com/danoprey/Crystal)

If memory serves I've had Miro installed before with good results.

Comment: Quite a few of those are alpha/dev and no IE support :( Thanks though

Comment: Yeah sorry I should've mentioned that, I haven't ever come across a decent stable one (didn't know about the IE support though. Probably time for that to die anyway!)